# Setting ftp server with different ip

Tags: ftp, ip

i already setup basic FTP server (via IIMS) on my computer with corporate IP let say it's 195.1.1.30 (just an example).. all the PC that connected within this area (195.1.1.1-255) can connect through..

when i change the ip into 195.1.[2].1-255.. they cannot access to that FTP

is there some ways so all the IP can access to that IP? no matter what the 3rd value is

Comment: Nope. Have people use your hostname, then when your IP address changes it'll still work.

Answer (score 0):

Q: is there some ways so all the IP can access to that IP? no matter what the 3rd value is?

A: No.  Because of the rules of TCP/IP.

192.168.1.x is a class C network, and 192.168.2.x is a *different* class C network:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940018.aspx

What you *should* be doing (especially in a corporate environment), is use a DNS hostname instead of an IPv4 address.

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the mask. If you were to simply change the subnet mask to a /16 - that is to say something like 255.255.0.0 - then, in your scenario, it wouldn't matter what number the client uses in the 3rd octet. This effectively changes it from a class C to a class B, but who cares since it's on a private network.